# Drupal 6 does not like it when an image tag's absolute path contains "http:"

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Drupal 6.28 and there's something i don't understand.

i have a page that contains an image tag pointing to an absolute path.
e.g.

```
<img alt="google logo" src="http://www.google.com.sg/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="height:190px; width:538px" />
```

when the content is saved, drupal returns a "Page Not Found" error.

i found out that if i remove the "http:" at the start of the src attribute, there wouldn't be any problem.  everything would be ok.
i.e.

```
<img alt="google logo" src="//www.google.com.sg/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="height:190px; width:538px" />
```

is there some setting that i may have messed up that causes this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you write the image tag in the body field or what?
what gives you 'page not found', the page or the image request?

Comment: hi guys, it turns out that it was caused by some mod_security setting by my host.

Comment: hi guys, it turns out that it was caused by some mod_security setting by my host. when i asked them what they changed to fix it, all they said was that they white listed something.